# How to center menu items in a navigation bar

Tags: jquery, html, css

I currently have a full width navigation bar here: [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/cupekaxu/32/edit)

But is there a way to have the widths of the menu items to expand such that they take up all of the navigation bar space as opposed to just being on the left?

I would like it so that if there were four menu items (say A, B, C, and D) that the navigation bar be split into four equal sections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the fixed width on the li element to a percentage.

For three equal parts

```
#navbar li{
float:left;
padding:10px 0px;
position:relative;
width:33.33333%;
}
```

For four equal parts

```
#navbar li{
float:left;
padding:10px 0px;
position:relative;
width:25%;
}
```

Comment: I've tried doing this, but this seems to ruin the dropdown list items' sizes. See here, when you hover over B or C: http://jsbin.com/cupekaxu/35/edit. How would I resize the dropdown menu items so that they are the same width as A, B, and C?

Comment: Thats because you don't have a style for the drop down li elements, so they pick up the first li style. [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/yijaquwu/2/edit)

Comment: You got it! If this answer helped, make sure to accept it as the correct answer for future reference for others.

Comment: I added my explanation of adding #navbar li li{width:100%;} before seeing your JSBIN link. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

To create the same width independently of the elements number you need to use this:

```
  #navbar{ 
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width:100%
  }
  #navbar > li { 
    display:table-cell; 
    float:none !important;
    width:auto !important;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put a div wrapper around your navbar and set its width to 100% and align text center. Then set your ul navbar to display as inline-block. Doing it this way, you can have any number of items and it will center them.

```
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color:#40CC9D;
}
ul {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/jayetaqa/1/edit)